# shopify - Load Products using Ajax-Call from particular Collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, collections, shopify, liquid

I'm new in Shopify. I did 2 Shopify website theme development. But today I'm stuck in a simple work. I know someone expert on Shopify can help me out.

One of my client wants to show few products on homepage using ajax call. Concept is this: Slideshow will play. when user click on image from slideshow it will loads products under that slideshow. every image link on that slide show will represent a COLLECTION. It could be COLLECTION.ID / COLLECTION.HANDLE. But I need to load all products under the slideshow on ajax-call from a particular Collection.

For example, In homepage will loads 6 top COLLECTIONS. When user click on "boots" collection then few latest products from "boots" collection will be shows on homepage into particular section. Same way, when user click on "belt" collection then few latest products under "belt" collection will be shows on homepage into particular section.

Note: My client don't want to add/assign "featured collection" in homepage. It needs fully dynamically.

Thanks in advance to all of those person, who tries to help me :)

Comment: You cannot get collection information using the shopify AJAX api. http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api

Comment: I hope you understand the requirements ... so can you suggest me any way to achieve this?